# Iniciar aplicação em um monitor específico no Adobe AIR

Tags: windows, actionscript-3, flash, adobe-air

Estou a desenvolver uma aplicação em Adobe Air exe que usa 2 monitores, a aplicação calcula quantos monitores tem o computador, e calcula usando um rectangle para popular os mesmos.

Por aqui está tudo bem, a minha questão é porque o cursor do rato tem a decisão de ser o monitor principal.

Por exemplo: Se eu abrir a aplicação no ecrã esquerdo, a aplicação começa no ecrã esquerdo, se abrir a aplicação no ecrã direito, a aplicação abre no ecrã direito.

Existe alguma maneira de impedir que o rato faça a gestão do monitor principal?

Comment: Até aonde sei o cursor na tela é parte da interface do Desktop e não da aplicação e ele é baseado na posição rato/mouse pelo usuário, se entendi você quer forçar o reposicionamento do cursor, eu acho isto uma péssima pratica, já que o cursor deve ser manipulado pelo usuário. É apenas uma opinião. Talvez eu não tenha entendido o que você perguntou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente, você precisa definir qual o monitor em que a aplicação será lançada, após isso, resgatar as informações da área de exibição desse monitor, para isso, utilize a classe [Screen](http://help.adobe.com/pt_BR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Screen.html), utilize `Screen.screens.length` para resgatar quantos monitores o usuário está utilizando:

```
var nMonitor:int = 0; //Número do primeiro monitor, por exemplo;
var areaVisivel:Rectangle = Screen.screens[nMonitor].visibleBounds; //Área do monitor
```

Ao iniciar a aplicação, você pode definir em que área ela será lançada:

```
//Deste jeito, com acesso ao stage da janela principal
stage.nativeWindow.x = areaVisivel.x + 100;
stage.nativeWindow.y = areaVisivel.y + 100;
//Ou deste jeito
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.activeWindow.x = areaVisivel.x + 100;
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.activeWindow.y = areaVisivel.y + 100;
```

Comment: Eu acho que o problema dele não é com a janela do Aplicativo e sim com o cursor do rato/mouse.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento difícil de compreender, eu levei em consideração a abertura do aplicativo, por exemplo, na barra de tarefas, onde o Windows cria duas barras de tarefas em monitores diferentes contendo o mesmos atalhos para aplicações. Quando você clica para abrir uma aplicação no monitor 1 a aplicação abre no monitor 1, se você clica para abrir no monitor 2, abre no monitor 2, e assim sucessivamente.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, outro motivo é ele ter dito "abrir aplicação" e nada relacionado ao "arrastar" ou "posicionar" o mouse/rato no lugar "x".

Comment: *Existe alguma maneira de impedir que o rato faça a gestão do monitor principal?* -- Rato no caso é o Mouse ou melhor o Cursor do sistema operacional na tela. O que ele quer é o cursor pra aparecer no monitor que está a instancia principal do app.

Comment: Falando agora só da pergunta, eu pessoalmente acho que manipular o mouse é uma péssima pratica: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80295/iniciar-aplicação-em-um-monitor-específico-no-adobe-air#comment163255_80295

Comment: Impossível manipular a posição do mouse com Adobe AIR. Este era meu outro motivo. Mas cá entre nós, melhor esperarmos alguma posição do OP. Rsrs

Comment: Obrigado a todos pela resposta. Acabei por usar a resposta do biio e resolveu a situação.